# How to remove duplicate items in a list?

Tags: python, list

[What I'm getting and what I need to get pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8JKZ.png)

```
text = "the faith that he had had had had an affect on his life"

dictionary = {}
text = text.split()
for word in text:
    key = len(word)
    if key in dictionary.keys():
        dictionary[key] += [word]
    else:
        dictionary[key] = [word]
return dictionary
```

For the word in the text, there are repeated words.
How do I return the dictionary with no repeated words?

Comment: Use a `set` instead

Comment: Please see picture

Comment: Don't post pictures. And I already told use, use a set instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
List=[]
c=1
For n in list:
        If(n==list[c]):
             list.pop(c)
        C+=1
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `set()`. Sets are basically lists that cannot have duplicated values. So, you convert your list to a `set` (it removes the duplicated values), and convert it back to a `list`

```
my_list = list('hello world')

def remove_duplicate(ls):
    return list(set(ls))

print(remove_duplicate(my_list))
```

The problem is that it doesn't keep the order of the list's items. (at least on python 3.4). So, you can make your own function:

```
my_list = list('hello world')

def remove_duplicate(ls):
    new = []
    for item in ls:
        if item not in new:
            new.append(item)
    return new

print(remove_duplicate(my_list))
```